# Solving warnings like match non exhaustive and calling polyequal in SML/NJ

Tags: pattern-matching, sml, smlnj

The Issue is to input two lists and repeat the elements in first list according the corresponding number in other list.
e.g. `repeat([2,3,4],[1,2,2])` would give `[2,3,3,4,4]`

```
fun repeat1(a,b)=if b>0 then a::repeat1(a,b-1) else [];
fun repeat([],[])=[]
|repeat([l1],[m1])=repeat1(l1,m1)
|repeat(l1::ln,m1::mn)=if length(l1::ln)=length(m1::mn) then if ln<>[] then repeat1(l1,m1)@repeat(ln,mn) else [] else [];
```

The error says

```
stdIn:36.64-36.66 Warning: calling polyEqual
stdIn:34.5-36.112 Warning: match nonexhaustive
          (nil,nil) => ...
          (l1 :: nil,m1 :: nil) => ...
          (l1 :: ln,m1 :: mn) => ...
```

What are these for (I know its for base cases and inductive cases are not sufficient)? But how do I remove this warning even though this does not effect the output of the program?. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obviously forgot two base cases when only one in two lists is empty. Since these cases are malformed inputs, you can use exception to handle them:

```
exception LengthNotEqual

fun repeat ([], []) = []
  | repeat ([], _) = raise LengthNotEqual
  | repeat (_, []) = raise LengthNotEqual
  | ...
```

After adding two new base cases, you don't need to compare lengths of two lists in the last pattern anymore. The use of `length` should be avoided since it will traverse the whole list once more. And the pattern `([l1], [m1])` could be removed due to redundancy.

So the new `repeat` function looks like:

```
fun repeat ([], []) = []
  | repeat ([], _) = raise LengthNotEqual
  | repeat (_, []) = raise LengthNotEqual
  | repeat (l1::ln, m1::mn) = repeat1(l1, m1)@repeat(ln, mn)
```